# How to check UI Element overlaps or not?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rect

I have to check whether two images (UI) are overlapping or not. I already use `rect.overlap()`, though output is really not acceptable, and `rect.contains` also does not work because both images are children of different parent. Is there any other way to calculate it?

Currently I'm playing with `RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint`, this function gives center of UI image so I can create new rect based on image center, but this will not be able to work for rotated image.